# Vuetify v-data-table with group by and v-slot customized row cause unexpected performance

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Vuetify version: 2.6.3
Vue version: 2.6.14

I have some question regarding to use vuetify v-data-table and its v-slot for customizing rows.
I have attach the code blew, when click pagination the top grouped header(w1,w2,w3) will always be checked unexpected(sometimes along with disable color) and previous selected groups are all gone. Does anyone can provide me some work around for the issue

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      item-key="name"
      @click:row="handleClick"
      class="elevation-1"
      group-by='class'
      :items-per-page="4"
    >
     <template v-slot:group.header="{items}">
       <th colspan="6">
         <v-checkbox :value=items[0].class>
           <template v-slot:label>
             {{ items[0].class }}
         </template>
         </v-checkbox>
         
       </th>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  methods:{
    handleClick(value)
    {
      console.log(value)
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      singleSelect: false,
      selected: [],
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
          class: 'w1'
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
          class: 'w2'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
          class: 'w2'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair2',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
          class: 'w2'
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair3',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
          class: 'w3'
        },{
          name: 'Eclair4',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
          class: 'w3'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

https://codepen.io/tymiao1220/pen/YzOWOqz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it happens, my guess is that Vue tries to re-use existing checkboxes when drawing the next page, and the internal state gets messed up.

But it goes away once you actually bind to a state, i.e. with data like

```
data () {
    return {
      selectedGroups: {w1: null, w2: null, w3: null},
```

you could do

```html
<v-checkbox :value="items[0].class" v-model=selectedGroups[items[0].class]>
```

Got to say, the `v-checkbox` props are confusing, between `:value`, `:true-value`/`:false-value`, `:input-value`, and `:model-value`.

In the documentation, it says `v-model` binds to [`:model-value`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-checkbox/#props-model-value), but that seems to be false, at least in the version you are using, it binds to `:input-value` (and the event it listens to is `@change`, not the usual `@input`).

The `:value` prop just sets the value attribute of the underlying input element, it probably does not make sense to use it unless you are working with regular form submissions. If you are working with async form data submission, the `:true-value` and `:false-value` are preferred.

Anyway, long story short, best to use `v-bind`, and then the weird behavior will stop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I like the idea of using state and it solves the problem!